# I want to upgrade my react-native version 0.39 to 0.40

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am facing lot of problems while installing new modules in 0.39 versions in react-native, but i am afraid if i will do upgrade  from 0.39 to 0.40 version it may be stop making build. Please guys suggest me how to upgrade or is there any benefits of upgrading my react-native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native is rapidly updating platform. Every version has a lot of bug fixes, new performance improvements and new or upgraded components. 
If its possible and feasible for you I suggest you to upgrade the latest stable version.
You can check the docs for [Upgrading React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html) for details on how to upgrade. There might be lots of changes since your version is fairly old. 
I suggest you to check every libraries (if you are using) if they are compatible with the new version of react-native and how you should upgrade the libraries.
There was some major changes on v0.40 of react native.

Comment: Is there any chances of stop making build or error comes out in react native while upgrading @bebygenel

Comment: Yes there is. If you have some incompatible library or code in your project  it might not build successfully. Please read the docs for upgrading react native.